# How to use Latin Modern Mono slanted instead of italics in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, latin-modern

I'd like to use Latin Modern Mono Slanted instead of Latin Modern Mono Italic, for typesetting code comments in a float environment. The first one is the default italic font (used for code comments), and the second one is what I want to achieve. How can I redefine the italic shape in XeLaTeX? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
    # Defining the sum function
    def sum(a, b):
        return a+b
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||, mathescape=true]{python}
    |\slshape{\texttt{Defining the sum function}}|
    def sum(a, b):
        return a+b
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latin Modern Mono has no slanted version, but you can use the separate Slanted font for italic. You also need to fake boldface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[
  BoldFont=*,
  ItalicFont=* Slanted,
  BoldItalicFont=* Slanted,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=4},
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=4},
]

\begin{document}

\texttt{\itshape Abc\bfseries Abc}

\begin{minted}{python}
    # Defining the sum function
    def sum(a, b):
        return a+b
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use Latin Modern Mono Light, which has oblique instead of italic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Light}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\itshape Abc\bfseries Abc}

\begin{minted}{python}
    # Defining the sum function
    def sum(a, b):
        return a+b
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]